# can we move project from Angular to Umbraco

Tags: angular, umbraco, project

I have create small project with ANGULAR 4

can we migrate/move it UMBRACO...

Is there will be any code diffrence ?

Any Suggestions will help me..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to use Umbraco as a CMS for your application.

1. Create API end points to give you the data you want your web application to consume. - have a look at:
   http://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-developers-guide/umbraco-web-api/how-to-create-a-web-api-in-umbraco-in-less-than-5-minutes
2. Then change your Angular application to point to these end points to drive your website.
3. Change something in Umbraco, then see the changes reflected in your web application.

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco is a Microsoft CMS, works with .NET, C#, a templating language called Razor.
This has nothing to do with Angular 4+ that uses ES6, TypeScript...

> Is there will be any code diffrence ?

Everything is different, Angular allows you to create single page applications using templating syntax, web components, etc. Umbraco, on the other hand, only allows you to give your .NET/C# backend a graphic user interface.

What I suggest you is to:

- Or you create an API in your backend .NET/C# environment and use it to feed data to your Angular application.
- Just use Umbraco, forget Angular.

But again, this is only my opinion.

Comment: Another way would be to use Umbraco as a headless cms and create umbracoapicontrollers to feed data to the angular application